# PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE vs SHIPTOSTATE

Tags: paypal

What is the difference between `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE` and `SHIPTOSTATE`?

I can't find from Paypal documentation any information about difference between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SHIPTOSTATE (as well as all the other parameters like that) are the old parameters that were used in Express Checkout before PayPal added the ability to do parallel payments in Express Checkout.

As such, SHIPTOSTATE is now deprecated (and listed as such in the [PayPal documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/).)

All of the fields that were setup that way got moved into PAYMENTREQUEST_n_PARAMNAME when they added parallel payments, so now you can have multiple payment requests in a single checkout, and each would have their own set of params.

So at this point, even if you're only setting up a single payment, you want to go with PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PARAMNAME.